# Django listing matching query does not exist, but the page renders correctly and error displays only in terminal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm having a problem with Django models. I'm trying to compare value(price) stored in a listing model, but I can't because it is recognized as None, but it clearly displays on webpage with no errors.

models.py:

```
class listing(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Title}"
```

views.py:

```
def listing_page(request, listing_id):
    item=listing.objects.get(Title=listing_id) (Here terminal throws error: auctions.models.listing.DoesNotExist)
    price=item.price
    bids=bid.objects.filter(listing=item)
    form=bidForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            if price < form:
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {"listing":item, "form":form, "bids":bids})
```

Full error Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\levan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\levan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response     
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\levan\Downloads\commerce (2)\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 39, in listing_page
    item=listing.objects.get(Title=listing_id)
  File "C:\Users\levan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method      
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\levan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
auctions.models.listing.DoesNotExist: listing matching query does not exist.
```

UPDATE: added urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("add", views.add, name="add"),
    path("mylistings", views.mylisting, name="mylistings"),
    path("<str:listing_id>", views.listing_page, name="listing"),  
]
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure that you have `listing` object in the database with the `listing_id` that you provided as argument?

Comment: Why the request says `/favicon.ico`? Please add the `urls.py`. The issue seems to be that your view handles the favicon request instead of the static view

Comment: Done! I've added urls.py